# R, how to create a binary relation matrix from a list of strings?

Tags: r, matrix, contingency

I have a list of files that contain specific genes, and I want to create a binary relation matrix in R that shows the presence of each gene in each file.

For example, here are my files `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, and `ddd` and the genes associated to them.

```
aaa=c("HERC1")
bbb=c("MYO9A", "PKHD1L1", "PQLC2", "SLC7A2")
ccc=c("HERC1")
ddd=c("MACC1","PKHD1L1")
```

I would like to know which command I could use in R to generate a binary relation table like the one in the following image:

[image]

where the value 1 means association, and the value 0 means non-association.

How can I do this operation in R?

I tried to use `table(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd)` but it did not work. R said:

> Error in table(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd) :    all arguments must have the
>   same length

**EDIT**: Thanks @akrun for your useful reply! I'll take advantage of this question to ask help for **another issue**, that I'm sure you guys can handle very quickly. For the second part of my analysis, I need to generate another table that where, **for each pair of genes, I assign the value 1 if both of them present in the specific file, and 0 other wise**. Following the example that I gave earlier, this new table should look like the following one (I transpose it for clarify):

[image]

Does anybody know a quick way to obtain this new bigenic table in R, starting from the commands you guys already provided to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to get the values of the object identifiers in a named `list` (`mget`), `stack` it to a two column data.frame and get the frequency with `table`

```
table(stack( mget(strrep(letters[1:4], 3)))[2:1])
#   values
#ind   HERC1 MACC1 MYO9A PKHD1L1 PQLC2 SLC7A2
#  aaa     1     0     0       0     0      0
#  bbb     0     0     1       1     1      1
#  ccc     1     0     0       0     0      0
#  ddd     0     1     0       1     0      0
```

---

Or an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd) %>% 
  enframe %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  name  HERC1 MACC1 MYO9A PKHD1L1 PQLC2 SLC7A2
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 aaa       1     0     0       0     0      0
#2 bbb       0     0     1       1     1      1
#3 ccc       1     0     0       0     0      0
#4 ddd       0     1     0       1     0      0
```

---

In the OP's code

```
table(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd)
```

the `length` of the `vector`s need to be same for `table` to work.  In addition, if we use more than 2 vectors, the frequency table will be multi-dimensional (> 2D).  So, we need a framework to have the `table` applied on two columns instead of multiple objects

Comment: thanks, very fast! Regarding the `table(stack` solution, how do you specify the variables `aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd`? My request is actually a prototype; the real task has hundreds of variables with more complicated names.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it  I created the string identifiers with `strrep` and `letters`, or instead it can be also `mget(c("aaa", "bbb", .))`,  e.g. `strrep("a", 3)` gives `"aaa"`

Comment: @DavideChicco.it  If there is no pattern in the names and if the session have only the objects from those, then use `mget(ls())`  Having said that, you would be having the identifiers while creating it right?

Comment: Off topic, but just reading the code, I've already knew who wrote it)

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your help; can you please help me with the new part of the question too?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it  You can post it as a new question

Comment: @akrun Okay, new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193505/r-how-to-create-a-binary-relation-matrix-of-pair-occurrences-from-a-list-of-str